# Create a session function to protect controllers direct access

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I already registered session with my code and preventing the the profile direct access with following code.

```
public function profile() {
    if ($this->session->userdata('logged_in')) {
        //var_dump($this->session->userdata['logged_in']);
        $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
        $data['nric_number'] = $session_data['nric_number'];

        $this->load->view('templates/header');
        $this->load->view('layouts/employee/profile', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    } else {
        //If no session, redirect to login page
        $base = base_url();
        redirect($base . 'checkinout', 'refresh');
    }
}
```

Suppose, I am going prevent another controller named `allusers`. So, Script will be something like below-

```
public function allusers() {
    if ($this->session->userdata('logged_in')) {
        $this->load->view('layouts/employee/allusers');

    } else {
        //If no session, redirect to login page
        $base = base_url();
        redirect($base . 'checkinout', 'refresh');
    }
}
```

But, I would not like to use following condition for each method. Can I skip actually?

```
if($this->session->userdata('logged_in')) {
} else {
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put the code in your constructor of class, in this way you dont need to check for the session in all methods!

```
    if(!($this->session->userdata('logged_in'))) {
         $allowed = array(
             'method1',
             'method2'
         );

      if ( ! in_array($this->router->fetch_method(), $allowed) {
        redirect('login');
      }
    }
```

Comment: If I put exit with my magic method what will happen actually. Will it redirect to my login page?

Comment: no! script just stops executing there! better put a redirect there! wait i will edit my answer

Comment: What is your suggestion for this if do something like follows?
`if(!($this->session->userdata('logged_in'))) {
$base = base_url();
redirect($base . 'checkinout', 'refresh');
}`

Comment: yes! that would be correct! you dont even need to use base_url everywhere, just do it like i shown in answer

Comment: Another question raised here If I put it in magic method that is- Can I give permission directly for one method from that class?

Comment: i didnt understood, please explain your question!

Comment: If I put this code in __construct you suggest. Can I access a method from that class without session registered?

Comment: yes! you can, its a bit tricky, but it can be done. i will edit my answer again!

Comment: its really tricky.. I appreciate your answer. I will happy if you appreciate my question. Thanks

Comment: i already voted up your question because i found your question informative which will help others too